# CaseNumber is not visible after case creation

Tags: apex, case, auto-number

I am having a facing a problem with CaseNumber.

I am creating a case object with all the mandatory field in my apex code.

```
 Case caseObject = new Case(DBG_Country__c = country,                                  
                               Description = descp
                         ......);
 insert case;
 System.debug('*****CaseNumber'+caseObject.CaseNumber);
```

In the above debug the CaseNumber is coming as null. Isn't case number generated when the case is created? just like the case record id? Then why am I not being able to view it in the next step?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to execute a query to retrieve any fields that are populated automatically when you perform DML, *except `Id`*. `Id` is the only field the system will automatically populate in your sObjects when you perform an insert.

Here, you must do

```
caseObject = [SELECT CaseNumber FROM Case WHERE Id = :caseObject.Id];
```